# Configure mysql 5.0.18 on CentOS 6.3

Tags: mysql

Please help me configure and run 'mysql 5.0.18' on CentOS 6.3.

I have installed using mysql5.0.18 tarball. can't find the bin folder inside. Not sure what to do further.

Thanks.

Comment: why version 5.0.18? why not install regular yum way mysql 5.5 at least? >>yum install mysql55w mysql55w-server

Comment: I have mysql 5.5 also. I need to integrate it with Spark 1.6.0

Comment: it doesn't work with a higher version? 5.0 is outdated

Comment: Same issue with mysql 5.5. How do I configure it. Can't find much about it.

Answer (score 0):

To install mysql 5.5 on Centos 6:

```
 yum install mysql55w mysql55w-server
```

or : yum install mysql mysql-server

try prepending sudo, if doesn't work.

- After that:

  ```
  chkconfig mysqld on
  mysql_secure_installation
  ```

chkconfig is to make sure that mysql is started upon reboot. 
mysql_secure_installation for securing mysql

Comment: Thanks Muhammed. I think I was able to install mysql 5.7 on CentOS 6.3 using a tarball but it didn't create 'mysql.sock' file while installation. I got to know that I will need to run 'mysql_upgrade' to get it created but I couldn't do it due to access issues(don't know the root password). What should I do to resolve this?? Can I get this file from somewhere so if I place it at the correct path and make mysql run. Please help with this. Thanks.

Comment: try adding sudo before yum